# How to add random music for video with ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, video-conversion, mixer

I'm a new user of FFmpeg, I want to add random music (defined folder) for multiple video with ffmpeg ?

Specifically: I have a FFmpeg command, i used to process multiple videos in the folder at the same time

```
@ECHO OFF

Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set INPUT=D:\Shorts\code\INPUT
set OUTPUT=D:\Shorts\code\OUTPUT

:: encode video:

for %%a in ("%INPUT%\*.*") DO ffmpeg -i "%%a" -i "MUSIC\*.mp3" -c copy -preset slow -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest -y "%output%\%%~na.mp4"

pause
```

**error can't find music file**

[image]

**Please help me?**

Comment: @Gyan Please help me?